# Finding the value of git-config `push.default` on my system?

Tags: git

From the [Git Config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
push.default
    Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given.
```

How do I find out the value of `push.default`on my system?

I just did `git push` intending to push only the current branch, however I ended up pushing other branches too.

Comment: `git config --system --get push.default`

Comment: @RomainValeri Does not work, no output is shown.

Comment: If nothing is shown, the default is the compiled-in default. For Git versions predating 2.0, that's `matching`; for 2.0 or later, that's `simple`.

Answer (score 2):

With `git config --system --get push.default`.

If you have no output, it means that git has no config entry at this level.

It might, however, have it recorded at another level, like `--global` or `--local`

To be sure, don't ask for a specific level by just omitting the `--system` flag.

In the past, the default value for `push.default` setting at git install was `matching`, which *does* push every branch to its matching counterpart. It changed at some point to now `simple`, which just pushes the current branch.

Comment: BTW, the default is `simple` for v2.0 or better.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Thanks for the precision, it slipped my mind. Editing to add it.

Comment: I have no output for neither `--global` nor `--local` nor `--system`. Maybe the question is how do I know what is the default value?

Comment: @Danijel What does `git --version` output?

Comment: `git version 2.20.1` So my default should be `simple`, but seems like it isn't.

Comment: @Danijel It *should* be `simple`. How did you push? CLI? software? if CLI, what command exactly?

Comment: @Danijel you can always set it explicitly: `git config --global push.default simple`.  This is what I do, but I prefer `current`. :-)  But if your version is 2.20.1 and things are behaving differently, then perhaps an old version is being picked up somewhere along the way.

Comment: I was working in `branchA` where I commited "work in progress", and did not intend to push it yet. Then I switched to `branchB`, commited some work and then I did `git push`. To my surprise, I later realized that my "work in progress" from `branchA` was pushed too.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I feel reluctant to set the flag myself before I find out the reason how could this "accidental" commit happen.

Comment: @Danijel I'd probably go the other way and set it, so that nothing unexpected happens from a push standpoint, and then try and figure out what's going on.  I did check recent work in Git, and I don't see anything related to issues with the push.default setting.  So it smells like something else is going on, or you perhaps pushed things without realizing it.

Comment: One thing that might be important: the remote repository is on BitBucket. If you look at their [Supported Platforms](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/supported-platforms-776640981.html) page, you'll see it says "Git client 1.8.4.3". Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

`git config push.default` prints the value if it's set. If `--show-origin` is used, it also prints where the value is defined. If the value is empty, it's not set at all. Besides `push.default`, `branch.<name>.merge` with `branch.<name>.remote` also has effect on the push behaviour. `<name>` is the name of the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first fetch the list of all the global config variables initialised on your system. You get them by using the following command:

```
git config --list
```

After this a list of all the variables will be displayed. Find `push.default` in it. If there is a variable by that name, then the following command as mentioned by @RomainValeri will get you the desired result:

```
git config --system --get push.default
```

If you cannot find the above variable but want to set it, then you can set it by using the following command:

```
git config --system push.default "Your value here"
```